# How to put assertion when you are successfully connected to database in the step definition file of cucumber

Tags: database, cucumber, connection, assertion, file-copying

Here in my below stepdefinition file for the below three methods i want to put assertions when i connect to db, data is deleted my db and when my files are copied

```
    @Given("^Connecting to the database$")
    public void connecting_to_the_database() throws Throwable {
        conn= DbUtil.getConnection( Config.DBUrl, Config.DBUsername, Config.DBPassword);
        DbUtil.executeQuery(conn,"select * from xyz ");
    }
    
    @Then("^Remove the table data$")
    public void remove_the_table_data() throws Throwable {
        DbUtil.executeSQLFile(conn, Constants.sqldeldata);
        
    }
    

    @Given("^Files are copied to the tmp folder$")
    public void files_are_copied_to_the_tmp_folder() throws Throwable {
     FileCopyUtil.copyToDir();   
     System.out.println("Files are copied");   
     }
```

Here in my below stepdefinition file for the below three methods i want to put assertions when i connect to db, data is deleted my db and when my files are copied

```
    @Given("^Connecting to the database$")
    public void connecting_to_the_database() throws Throwable {
        conn= DbUtil.getConnection( Config.DBUrl, Config.DBUsername, Config.DBPassword);
        DbUtil.executeQuery(conn,"select * from xyz ");
    }
    
    @Then("^Remove the table data$")
    public void remove_the_table_data() throws Throwable {
        DbUtil.executeSQLFile(conn, Constants.sqldeldata);
        
    }
    

    @Given("^Files are copied to the tmp folder$")
    public void files_are_copied_to_the_tmp_folder() throws Throwable {
     FileCopyUtil.copyToDir();   
     System.out.println("Files are copied");   
     }
```

Comment: So what is your issue? From your code it is not clear with what exactly you experience difficulties.

Comment: Let's take first scenario if i am not connected to database then the assertion should be false similarly if my files are not copied to /tmp/in folder then the assertion should fail.If the data is not removed from certain table assertion should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take first scenario if i am not connected to database then the assertion should be false similarly if my files are not copied to /tmp/in folder then the assertion should fail.If the data is not removed from certain table assertion should fail.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).